# Which PHP Array function should I use?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [type] => field
        [remote_name] => Title
        [my_name] => title
        [default_value] => http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [type] => field
        [remote_name] => BookType
        [my_name] => book-type
        [default_value] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [type] => value
        [remote_name] => dvd-disc
        [my_name] => dvd
        [default_value] => 
    )
)


Array
(
[title] => Test
[book-type] => dvd
)
```

I need to take each key in the second array, match it with the `my_name` value in the first array and replace it with the corresponding `remote_name` value of the first array while preserving the value of the second array.

There's got to be some c`array`zy function to help!

EDIT: There will also be a few cases that the `value` of the second array will need to be replaced by the `value` of the first array's `remote_name` where the value of the second array matches the value of the first array's `my_name`. How can I achieve this?

EG: `book-type => dvd` should turn into `BookType => dvd-disc`

Comment: +1 because you're so damn p(h)unny

Comment: How can you replace a value in the second array while preserving the value of the second array?  Abstraction overflow.

Comment: to clarify - I want to basically replace the key of the second array with the `remote_name` value of the first array that contains the second array's key as the first array's `my_name` value.............clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so?:

```
$first = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'type' => 'field',
        'remote_name' => 'Title',
        'my_name' => 'title',
        'default_value' => 'http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'type' => 'field',
        'remote_name' => 'BookType',
        'my_name' => 'book-type',
        'default_value' => '',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'type' => 'value',
        'remote_name' => 'dvd-disc',
        'my_name' => 'dvd',
        'default_value' => '',
    ),
);

$second = array(
    'title' => 'Test',
    'book-type' => 'dvd',
);

$map = array('fields' => array(), 'values' => array());
foreach ($first as $entry) {
    switch ($entry['type']) {
        case 'field':
            $map['fields'][$entry['my_name']] = $entry['remote_name'];
            break;

        case 'value':
            $map['values'][$entry['my_name']] = $entry['remote_name'];
            break;
    }
}

$new = array();
foreach ($second as $key => $val) {
    $new[isset($map['fields'][$key]) ? $map['fields'][$key] : $key] = isset($map['values'][$val]) ? $map['values'][$val] : $val;
}

print_r($new);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [Title] => Test
    [BookType] => dvd-disc
)
```

**Explanation**:

The first loop collects the my_name/remote_name pairs for fields and values and makes them more accessible.
Like so:

```
Array
(
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title
            [book-type] => BookType
        )

    [values] => Array
        (
            [dvd] => dvd-disc
        )

)
```

The second loop will traverse `$second` and use the key/value pairs therein to populate `$new`. But while doing so will check for key/value duplicates in `$map`.

Keys or values not found in the map will be used *as is*.

Comment: hurts my brain, but looks pretty good. how would you approach adding it to a new results array instead of modifying the second array?

Comment: @Dave Kiss See the updated example. Not much changed, just using `$new` as container for the data.

Comment: actually, are you still around? I have one more loop to throw in this question

Comment: @Dave Kiss Is it correct to assume that `[type] => value` entries should overwrite values and `[type] => field` entries, the keys?

Comment: @Yoshi your assumptions are confirmed

Comment: @Yoshi just trying to comprehend this solution - is it set so that not all values of the second array are replaced by something that exists in the first array? I only want to replace it if a match is found

Comment: @Dave Kiss I added an explanation, hope it helps. ;)

Comment: You are amazing. One of the best answers I've had on here. A+++++++ would vote again.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr1 as &$el) {
    $el['remote_name'] = $arr2[$el['my_name']];
}
unset($el);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a c`array`zy function, but I know how you could do it:

```
//$array1 is first array, $array2 is second array

foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    if (isset($value['remote_name'], $value['my_name']) && $value['remote_name'] && $value['my_name']){
        $my_name = $value['my_name'];
        if (isset($array2[$my_name])) {
            $remote_name = $value['remote_name'];
            $array2[$remote_name] = $array2[$my_name];
            //cleanup
            unset($array2[$my_name]);
        }
    }
}
```